# Display only a directory name

Tags: php, regex

I try to develop a function to display only directory start by **Odoo**
We can have **Odoo8, Odoo9, Odoo10 ...** but also others directories.

How to display just **Odoox** directories in a dropdown

I start by that. It display all directories inside specific directory

```
  function  cfg_set_all_template_directory_hook_odoo_pull_down($value){

    $name = (!empty($key) ? 'configuration[' . $key . ']' : 'configuration_value');

    $template_directory = OSCOM::getConfig('dir_root', 'Shop') . 'includes/Module/Hooks/Admin/';

    $weeds = array('.', '..', '_notes', 'index.php', '.htaccess', 'README');

    $directories = array(scandir($template_directory), $weeds);
    $filename_array = array();


    foreach($directories as $value) {
      if(is_dir($template_directory.$value)) {
        $filename_array[] = array('id' => $value,
                                  'text' => $value);
      }
    }

    return HTML::selectMenu($name, $filename_array, $value);
  }
```

Comment: did you try regex? http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: After obtaining $directories you can use a regex or loop to obtain only Odoo one's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside the foreach you can put with your if this condition

```
foreach($directories as $value) {
     if(is_dir($template_directory.$value) && preg_match("/Odoo.+/", $value)) {
         $filename_array[] = array('id' => $value,'text' => $value);
      }
    }
```